# Passing objects to Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, cloud

I try to understand the capabilities of Spark, but I fail to see if the following is possible in Python.

I have some objects that are non Pickable (wrapped from C++ with SWIG).
I have a list of those objects obj_list = [obj1, obj2, ...]
All those objects have a member function called .dostuff

I'd like to parallelized the following loop in Spark (in order to run it on AWS since I don't have a big architecture internally. We could probably use multiprocessing, but I don't think I can easily send the objects over the network):

[x.dostuff() for x in obj_list]

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: How many of those objects do you have (in GBytes)? Does they fit in RAM all together on one machine?

Comment: "Parallelize a loop" I'm not sure what does that mean.

Comment: The "idea" is: as the dostuff is not isotime (1 can take ms to compute, one can take 2 minutes, and I have loads of them) depending on the object, I'd like to send them on a network to reduce the global computing time.

Answer (score 0):

If your object's aren't picklable your options are pretty limited. If you can create them on the executor side though (frequently a useful option for things like database connections), you can `parallelize` a  regular list (e.g. maybe a list of the constructor parameters) and then use `map` if your `dostuff` function returns (picklable) values you want to use or `foreach` if your dostuff function is called for its side effects (like updating a database or similar).